# list is not added to the arraylist in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code I am fetching the data from server and then response added to the arraylist.

But it is displaying only one value..

can any one help me where i did the mistake

output:

```
{"list":[{"email":"Narendra.Varada@chipmonk.in","id":"2","mobileNumber":"6728768768","username":"Narendra1993"},{"email":"abc@gmail.com","id":"4","mobileNumber":"6253957809","username":"abc"}]}

I/System.out: [{"email":"Narendra.Varada@chipmonk.in","id":"2","mobileNumber":"6728768768","username":"Narendra1993"},{"email":"abc@gmail.com","id":"4","mobileNumber":"6253957809","username":"abc"}]
I/System.out: {"email":"Narendra.Varada@chipmonk.in","id":"2","mobileNumber":"6728768768","username":"Narendra1993"}
```

For the above output these are the results:

```
Username     Email       MobileNumber
abc          abc@gmail.com   6253957809
```

Second one is not displaying.

```
 try {
                                arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (Lists);
                                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray ("list");
                                System.out.println (result);

                                for (int i=0;i<result.length ();i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject ( );
                                    jsonObject1 = result.getJSONObject(i);
                                    System.out.println (jsonObject1);
                                    String email = result.getJSONObject (i).getString ("email");
                                    String mobile = result.getJSONObject (i).getString ("mobileNumber");
                                    username = jsonObject1.getString ("username");
                                    arrayList.add (username);
                                    arrayList.add (email);
                                    arrayList.add (mobile);
                                    tvName.setText (username);
                                    tvEmail.setText (email);
                                    tvMobile.setText (mobile);
                                    System.out.println ("username"+username);
                                }
```

Comment: Where is your output Code ? and don't use `tvName.setText()` in forloop. Cause it will provide you the last element of List

Comment: completely wrong approach

Answer (score 1):

The code you have tried in your for loop.

```
tvName.setText (username);
tvEmail.setText (email);
tvMobile.setText (mobile);
```

**Explanation why it is showing the only output for abc user :**

As normally your trying to set Text to your TextViews. It is working perfectly but you can not see them because it is keep calling inside for loop.

**Reason why it is showing abc element :**

The abc is last user from ArrayList. When for loop reach to last element. It attach the last element data to TextView.

I Suggest to use the [RecyclerView](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example)

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this.

#### First,Create your user pojo.

```
public class UserInfo {
private String email;
private String id;
private String mobileNumber;
private String username;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
}

public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

}

#### Second.update your parse code.

```
            try {
                    arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (Lists);
                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray ("list");
                    System.out.println (result);

                    for (int i=0;i<result.length ();i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        System.out.println (jsonObject1);
                        String email = result.getJSONObject (i).getString 
                        ("email");
                        String mobile = result.getJSONObject 
                         (i).getString ("mobileNumber");
                        username = jsonObject1.getString ("username");
                        UserInfo userInfo=new UserInfo();
                        userInfo.setEmail(email);
                        userInfo.setMobileNumber(mobile);
                        userInfo.setUsername(username);
                        arrayList.add (userInfo);
                        System.out.println ("username"+username);
                    }
                        tvName.setText (arrayList.get(0).getUsername());
                        tvEmail.setText (arrayList.get(0).getEmail());
                        tvMobile.setText 
                        (arrayList.get(0).getMobileNumber());
                   }
```

Now,the arrayList has what you want. you also can show what you want decide the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Model class to bind the data .

```
public class users {
    String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String email;
    String name;
}
```

Create object of this Model and set data to the object using set methods

```
users u=new users();
u.setEmail(username);
.
.
.
```

Add this object to Arraylist;

```
arraylist.add(u);
```

after that you have to create RecyclerView . There are lots of tutorials for the same on internet.